# Uploading single file using jquery in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, file-upload

i want to implement the simple file upload without flash.. and single file, but with jquery, there should not be any postbacks...

can anyone suggest some jquery code for uploading file to the server.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are only trying to upload a single file, I would use the upload control and then use a JQuery progress bar like one of the controls here:
http://dj.codeplex.com/

If you use the extender and updatepanel, there will be no postbacks.